# RESTful API design differentiate operations on identical URI with same HTTP Method

Tags: rest, http, web, interface

I would like to design a RESTful API in order to control a Bluetooth Dongle over a web interface.

What happens if I have the following conflict

```
POST /IDofDongle/
```

Let's say I want this specific USB dongle to either start a discovery/inquiry process (append information about surrounding Bluetooth devices to the resource) or connect to any Bluetooth device (create a new subordinate resource by appending the MAC Address of the Bluetooth device to the URI above)?

Differentiating using a QueryString seems very RPC like to me.
Or do I need to define other resources?

Comment: Why do you want to use a RESTful API for controlling a dongle?

Answer (score 1):

You've run into the REST fallacy. Not everything is a resource, so you shouldn't try to treat everything as such. By POSTint to that endpoint, you're saying you want to create an USB dongle. As you aren't accessing a 3D printer, this won't work. You *are* building an RPC service.

So break with REST and introduce your own verbs:

```
POST /IDofDongle/Discover
POST /IDofDongle/Connect
```

Of course you could treat "discoveries" and "connections" as a resource:

```
POST /IDofDongle/Discoveries
POST /IDofDongle/Connections
```

"Creating" those entities. You can then return a Discovery or Connection entity that relates to the specified dongle, holding the relevant properties for such entities (DiscoveredDevices, ConnectionID, ...).